# Isomorphism of algebras $E_v = \prod_{w\mid v} E_w$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory, algebras

I am currently reading the article

> Bayer–Fluckiger, Eva, B. Nivedita, and Raman Parimala. "Hasse principle for G–quadratic forms." Documenta Mathematica 18 (2013): 383-392.

in which there is a side remark which I would like to see a proof of. Unfortunatly I can neither find one in the literature nor have I been able to prove the statement myself so far. I'll briefly explain the setup.

Let $k$ be a global field of characteristic $\neq 2$ and $E$ a finite-dimensional simple $k$-algebra. If $v$ is a place of $k$ and $w$ a place of a finite extension field $K|k$ lying above $v$, we write $w\mid v$. Put $E_v := E \otimes_k k_v$.
Now, the side remark I mentioned is "Note that $E_v = \prod_{w\mid v} E_w$."

What I have found so far is a similar statement for separable extions of valuated fields in Neurkich's Algebraic Number Theory, namely Theorem (8.3) of chapter II in the German edition.

> If $L|K$ is separable, we have $L\otimes_K K_v \cong \prod_{w\mid v} L_w$.

Neukirch's proof of this theorem relies on the separability condition, in that it uses a primitive element $\alpha$, such that $L=K(\alpha)$. In the paper I am reading there is no mentioning of separability and clearly for a global field such as $\mathbb{F}_p(T)$ I cannot assume separability of an arbitrary extension.

Do you have any hints for me as to how I might be able to prove that there is an isomorphism $E_v \cong \prod_{w\mid v} E_w$ or does perhaps someone know of a suitable reference where I might find the proof of this statement?

PS: Note that the requirement $\mathrm{char}(k)\neq 2$ may be unrelated to the validity of the statement in question. I've just copied it from the setup in the article.

Comment: This isn't true, as far as I know. In fact, the natural map $\displaystyle L\otimes_k k_v\to\prod_{w\mid v}L_w$ (which is surjective_ has kernel equal to the Jacobson radical of $L\otimes_k k_v$ (which is an Artinian ring). If you have non-separability then this Jacobson radical needn't be zero, and thus they shouldn't be isomorphic.

Comment: As a reference to my claims, you can see Pete L Clark's notes here http://math.uga.edu/~pete/8410FULL.pdf. It is on the end of page 45.

Comment: @Alex: Have you ruled out the possibility that the assumption that $E$ is *simple* as a $k$-algebra gets around the problem of non-separability?

Comment: Is the property of being simple stable under extension of scalars? Being *central simple* surely is, so if we view $E$ as an algbera over its center (a finite extension of $k$) we may make some progress...

Comment: Even if the finite extension $K/k$ is not necessarily separable, $K\otimes_k k_v$ is still reduced because $k$ being a global field, the extension $k\to k_v$ is separable (Dedekind domain of characteristic $0$ and finite type algebras over a field are "excellent"). Then use the link given by Alex. The characteristic of $k$ is not relevant here. So $K\otimes_k k_v\cong \prod K_w$. Then tensoring with $E$ over $k$ gives the isomorphism you are after.

Comment: Hi eveyone, and thanks for your comments. @Cantlog I don't completely understand your answer, unfortunately. What do you mean by "reduced"? I only know this to mean "not containing nilpotent elements", which can't be the case here, for example $E=k^{n\times n}$ is not reduced in that sense. Also, is there a precise meaning of the term "excellent"? If you could maybe elaborate on this a bit or provide some additional reference, maybe post this as an answer, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: (1) Definition of a (non necessarily algebraic) separable extension $L/k$: for any reduced (i.e. nilpotent = 0) $k$-algebra $A$, $A\otimes_k L$ is reduced. Surely $M_n(k)$ is not reduced, but I didn't use it.  (2) A discrete valuation ring $R$ is excellent if Frac($\hat{R}$) is separable over Frac($R$). (3) Once you know that the DVR $O_{k,v}$ is excellent, its field of fractions $k_v$ is then separable over $k$ and $K\otimes_k k_v$ is then reduced. This implies the isomorphism of $K\otimes_k k_v$ with the product of the $K_w$. Now if you tensor this isomorphism with anything ...

Comment: e.g., $E$, you still have an isomorphism. Hope this helps. The notion of excellence can be found for instance in Matsumura's book "Commutative algebra".

Comment: Great, thank you very much.